# How to have material ui standard Texfiled style instead of outlines

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-select

How to change the style of [react-select](https://react-select.com/home) from outline to standard in terms of
[material-ui TexField Select](https://mui.com/components/text-fields/#select)

**Current react-select style**

[image]

**What style I want is**

[image]

How can I do that

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a custom styles object to the Select

```
  const customStyles = {
  control: () => ({
    // none of react-select's styles are passed to <Control />
   
    borderBottom: "1px solid black"
  })
};

export default function App() {
  return <Select placeholder="something else" styles={customStyles}  />;
}
```

https://react-select.com/home#custom-styles

Comment: how do i change lable from select to something else

Comment: Add a placeholder prop, i edited my answer